# Can I lock hyper-v virtual machine so that users won't be able to close it or minimize it

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v, hypervisor

I'm working on a project for a client to install HMI application on the client servers. The client has requested to install the application inside Hyper-v virtual machine so that in case the operating system crashes then it will be easy to restore it back through the virtual machine drive back-up.

However, the customer is asking me to lock the virtual machine so that the machine's operator should not be able to go to the host operating system and only work through the virtual machine alone.

If it is not possible with Hyper-v options, then is there any free 3rd party tool which can do the same job.

I will really appreciate any advice on this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I wasn't able to prevent computer users from closing the virtual machine application. However I did manage to mitigate the effect of closing the virtual machine.

First thing I did was setting up Remote Desktop to connect the host to the VM remotely through hyper-v virtual switch. Then I installed Allen Bradley DeskLock tool (It is a free tool that comes together with their FTView CD). Through DeskLock I have prevented the user from doing anything over the host (Locked the desktop) and I provided him with only one button to run Remote Desktop and open the VM whenever he closes it by mistake.

I don't think that this answers the question completely, but it was the only solution I found without touching the computer Registry